# Exercise 2, Chapter 3 Rudin Functional Analysis (first edition)

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to tackle the following exercise.

> Suppose $L^2=L^2([-1,1])$ with respect to the lebesgue measure. For each scalar $\alpha$ let $E_{\alpha}$ the set of $f$ continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(0) = \alpha$.  Prove that each $E_{\alpha}$ is convex and dense in $L^2$.

Convexity is easy to show. For the density not sure, I've been trying to show that every continuous linear functional that vanishes on a subspace containing $E_{\alpha}$ also vanishes for any $f$ in $L^2$. However i don't know if this is the right approach. Any help is appreciated.

I've seen an approach that works out an approximation of arbitrary precision, I wonder however if separation theorems can somewhat be used in this case as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following approach brings more functional analytic favor instead of heavy analysis and so fulfills what you expected.

As you have noted that, one can prove that $(\left<E_{\alpha}\right>)^{\perp}=\{0\}$. In other words, one shall prove that
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\varphi(x)dx=0,\quad\varphi\in E_{\alpha}
\end{align*}
implying that $f=0$ a.e.

Let $g\in C[-1,1]$ be arbitrary. Fix an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{N}(x)=g(x)+\dfrac{\alpha-g(0)}{(1+|x|)^{N}},
\end{align*}
so $\varphi_{N}(0)=\alpha$ and $\varphi_{N}\in E_{\alpha}$. By assumption, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\varphi_{N}(x)dx&=0\\
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx&=(g(0)-\alpha)\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|)^{N}}dx\\
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx&=2(g(0)-\alpha)\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^{N}}dx=2(g(0)-\alpha)\dfrac{1}{N-1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{N-1}}\right).
\end{align*}
Taking $N\rightarrow\infty$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx=0.
\end{align*}
Since $C[-1,1]$ is $L^{2}$ dense in $L^{2}[-1,1]$, we conclude by Riesz representation theorem (Hilbert theory version) that $f=0$ in $L^{2}$.

**EDIT:**

The above answer is not complete. It only shows that $\overline{\left<E_{\alpha}\right>}=L^{2}[-1,1]$. But we can use the same trick again:

For $g\in\left<E_{\alpha}\right>$, set again
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{N}(x)=g(x)+\dfrac{\alpha-g(0)}{(1+|x|)^{N}},
\end{align*}
so $\varphi_{N}\in E_{\alpha}$ and
\begin{align*}
\|g-\varphi_{N}\|_{L^{2}[-1,1]}=|\alpha-g(0)|\left(\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{1}{(1+|x|)^{2N}}dx\right)^{1/2}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
for large $N$.

Comment: I don't think $E_\alpha$ is a vector space, so it doesn't make much sense to talk about orthogonal complement, right? It doesn't have the group structure.

Comment: Also $\varphi(0)$ is not in $E_\alpha$, cause it should be $\varphi(0) = \alpha$.

Comment: Just consider $\left<E_{\alpha}\right>$, the spanning set of $E_{\alpha}$.

Comment: $\varphi_{N}(0)=g(0)+\dfrac{\alpha-g(0)}{(1+|0|)^{N}}=g(0)+\alpha-g(0)=\alpha$, so $\varphi_{N}\in E_{\alpha}$, no?

Comment: Hi, you wrote $\varphi_N(0) = 0$. The rest I think makes sense.

Comment: Hi sorry again. But haven't you shown that the "spanning set" is dense and not the actual set?

Comment: See the edited post, thanks.

Comment: Then in a sense my first part answer is nonsense at all. It doesn't really need to recourse to orthogonal property and all that. All you need to do is to acknowledge the density of continuous functions in $L^{2}$, and then you approximate the continuous function by the $\varphi_{N}$ trick, as shown in the edited part. For then this has nothing to do with any standard functional analysis method.

Comment: Sounds a bit strange I can't use any FA methods. There's a hint given in the textbook "Hint: what is $E_\alpha$". Which is the pre-image of the evaluation functional defined on the subspace of continuous functions in $L^2([-1,1])$. When I observed this together with convexity of the set I thought I could use a separation theorem to show the density. But I still don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the density of $E_\alpha$, let
$$\phi_\delta(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1 - \frac{|x|}{\delta} &  |x| \le \delta \\
      0      &\lvert x\rvert > \delta 
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\lVert \phi_\delta\rVert_2^2 = \frac{2}{3}\delta$. Let $f\in L^2$, and for $\epsilon > 0$, choose continuous $g$ such that $\lVert g - f \rVert_2 < \epsilon/2$. This is possible because the continuous functions of compact support are dense in $L^p \left(1\le p < \infty\right)$. Suppose $g(0) = \beta$, and let $$\tilde{g} = g + (\alpha - \beta)\phi_\delta,$$ where $\delta$ is chosen small enough that $\lVert \tilde g - g\rVert< \epsilon/2$. Then $\tilde{g}\in E_\alpha$, $\lVert \tilde g - f \rVert < \epsilon$, and we have shown that $E_\alpha$ is dense in $L^2$.

See also [Disjoint convex sets which cannot be separated by any continuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199230/disjoint-convex-sets-which-cannot-be-separated-by-any-continuous-linear-function?rq=1), which contains a similar density proof, and also a proof that $E_\alpha$ and $E_\beta$ ($\alpha\ne\beta$) cannot be separated by any continuous linear functional $\Lambda$ on $L^2$, as requested in Rudin's exercise.